# How to start another build definition in TFS 2012

Tags: tfs

I use TFS 2012. I need customize the default template of build definition so that at the end of the build, start another build definition.

Which element I should add to workflow?

Answer (score 1):

Use the well established [Community TFS Build Extensions](https://github.com/tfsbuildextensions/CustomActivities); there is a `QueueBuild` activity ready to use. For guidance on customizing study the [ALM Rangers' Build Guide](https://vsarbuildguide.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built in activity to chain a build.

i have a custom activity that i use to queue additional builds when i need them.

code is as below

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using System;
using System.Activities;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BuildTasks.Activities
{
    // Queue a new build from the same Team Project.
    [BuildActivity(HostEnvironmentOption.Agent)]
    public sealed class QueueNewBuildwithParam : CodeActivity
    {
        // The Team Project that the build definition belongs to.
        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<IBuildDetail> BuildDetail { get; set; }

        // The build definition to queue
        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<String> BuildDefinition { get; set; }

        // The ParamName
        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<String> ParamName { get; set; }

        // The Param Value
        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<String> ParamValue { get; set; }

        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            // Obtain the runtime value of the input arguments
            string buildDefinition = context.GetValue(this.BuildDefinition);
            IBuildDetail buildDetail = context.GetValue(this.BuildDetail);
            string paramValue = context.GetValue(this.ParamValue);
            string paramName = context.GetValue(this.ParamName);


            // Obtain the Team Project for the current build definition.
            string tfsProject = buildDetail.BuildDefinition.TeamProject;

            string configurationServerUri = buildDetail.BuildServer.TeamProjectCollection.Uri.ToString();

            TfsTeamProjectCollection server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(configurationServerUri));
            server.EnsureAuthenticated();
            IBuildServer buildServer = (IBuildServer)server.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));
            IBuildDefinition buildDef = buildServer.GetBuildDefinition(tfsProject, buildDefinition);
            IBuildRequest request = buildDef.CreateBuildRequest();
            request.ProcessParameters = UpdateBuildDefinitionParam(buildDef.ProcessParameters, paramName, paramValue);
            buildServer.QueueBuild(request);
        }

        private static string UpdateBuildDefinitionParam(string processParameters, string param, string newValue)
        {
            IDictionary<String, Object> paramValues = WorkflowHelpers.DeserializeProcessParameters(processParameters);
            paramValues[param] = newValue;
            return WorkflowHelpers.SerializeProcessParameters(paramValues);
        }
    }
}
```